# Javascript 2 way data binding, Not framework

Tags: javascript, data-binding

I am just trying to understand data binding in pure javascript.  When I create an input and attach an event listener such as 'input' and then call a function to replace the innerHTML of a div with that new input value, the div will mirror the input box as I am typing.

I am trying to get the div to update when the value of the input box changes without someone typing.  So if the input were to change because of some code:

```
inp.value = 'Testing'
```

instead of someone directly typing inside of it, I would like the text within the div to still mirror it.

I tried it with the 'change' event listener but that only works when the input box loses focus.  So I tried adding that into the code:

```
inp.focus();
inp.value = 'Testing';
inp.blur();
```

But that doesn't work either.
Here is a link to my jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mmpal78/7g0vqwgh/1/

I am guessing there must be a way to do this.  Thanks.

Comment: Simply call `inputEvent();` within your `test1` function... https://jsfiddle.net/7g0vqwgh/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So if the input were to change because of some code:
>
> ```
> inp.value = 'Testing'
> ```
>
> instead of someone directly typing inside of it, I would like the text within the div to still mirror it.

You can't do that, there is no event raised when `value` is set that way, nor will a `MutationObserver` see anything to report.

Instead, you either

- Disallow direct access (just as a policy thing) and have all setting go through your framework (and then have your framework update anything affected by the `value` change). KO does this by having you work through its "obervables." Or,
- Update at whatever you consider appropriate times, such as whenever you're done processing an event, probably by storing the latest value of `value` you've processed and then checking it against the current `value`. Angular 1 did something like that. Or,
- Explicitly update anything you know is affected by `value` in the code modifying `value` (but that doesn't scale, you **will** forget to do it).

Comment: Only workaround for this would be to call `inputEvent();` after changing the value via source code?

Comment: @NewToJS: That would update the div, but it's hardly two-way binding at that point. You're just changing the value then explicitly going off and updating the div.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean. I looked at the question too simple and thought of a simple fix rather than looking into depth.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm a bit late, but I post the answer anyway.

First, what you're trying to do is not a two-way data binding, a two-way data binding is if you change the variable value the element's value is changed and vise-versa.

I suggest you use a structure so that you can use it anywhere you like, it's a bit complicated but take a look at this simple example specific to what you're trying to do which you can extend with a little time spent: **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7g0vqwgh/5/)**

first you create your constructor:

```
var variable=function(){
  this.variables={};
}
```

then you create the prototypes (methods) of your constructor `create`, `bind`, `set` and `get` to create a new variable, bind it to an element, set or change the value of the variable and finally get the value of the variable:

```
variable.prototype.create=function(name){
    this.variables[name]={
    elem:'',
    value:'',
    event:new Event(name+'Change')
  };
}
variable.prototype.bind=function(name,element){
    this.variables[name].elem=document.querySelector(element);
}
variable.prototype.set=function(name,val){
    this.variables[name].value=val;
  this.variables[name].elem.dispatchEvent(this.variables[name].event);
}
variable.prototype.get=function(name){
    return this.variables[name].value;
}
```

then you create an instance of your structure:

```
var binding=new variable();
```

create your variable and bind it to the input element:

```
binding.create('myVar');
binding.bind('myVar','.input');
```

then you set an event listener for the change of the value on your input:

```
document.querySelector('.input').addEventListener('myVarChange',function(){
    this.value=binding.get('myVar');
    document.querySelector('#div1').innerHTML=binding.get('myVar');
});
```

then if the user inputs any text we set it to the variable:

```
document.querySelector('.input').addEventListener('input',function(){
    binding.set('myVar',this.value);
});
```

and finally change the variable's value on click of the button:

```
document.querySelector('#btn1').addEventListener('click',function(){
    binding.set('myVar','test');
});
```